# Usando MKDIR via shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script

estou tentando criar um diretório via shell script, usando o comando:

```
mkdir -m755 "/var/www/app.dominio.com/html/$1"
```

onde o nome da pasta é passado por parâmetro, está ficando com um sinal de interrogação "nome_da_pasta?" no final e o mesmo fica inacessível, o que devo fazer para que o mesmo seja criado corretamente?

Comment: Faltam mais detalhes: Como você está passando o nome do pasta? Como chama o seu script? Tem o script que tá fazendo? Fiz alguns testes e não tive esse *erro* que você está tendo

Comment: Descobri que o erro era o carácter de quebra de linha devido eu ter criado o script no windows.

Answer (score 1):

Como não passou mais detalhes (*nem dos testes que fez, e nem do seu script*), posso acabar sugerindo algo que já fez.

No script (*usando o seu exemplo*), você usa:

`mkdir -m755 "/var/www/app.dominio.com/html/$1"` (*exatamente como tá fazendo*)

E na chamada do script (*que é o mais importante*), você faz:

`$ ./meu_querido_script nome_da_pasta`

Se isso não funcionar, verifica as permissões no diretório, ou posta o seu script completo (*se existir*).

**obs:** *realizei os testes exatamente como citei e funcionou, se não funcionar podemos dar continuidade a discussão.*

Answer (score 0):

Depois de várias tentativas descobri que o problema era devido eu ter criado o script em windows, pois ele coloca um carácter de quebra de linha diferente do aceito no linux.